# How check if string contain a particular number?

Tags: r, string

I am trying to check if a string contains a particular number. Example:

```
 mywords<- c("harry","met","sally","subway 10","1800Movies","2345")
```

If i want to check if the strings have the number "1", I am expecting to have the following as result:

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

I was trying something with:

```
grepl("\\1", mywords)
```

but it works only for letters. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: grepl("1", mywords)

Comment: oh!.. it was very easy. Thank you very much.